# horizontal scrolling elements blocking a vertical scrolling list

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ListView that contains a list of rectangles with text. Sometimes the text in the Rectangles is too long to fit so I would like the text to scrollable horizontally. I'm using a ScrollView surrounding the text to make it horizontally scrollable.

The problem is, I can't scroll through the list (vertically) because the scrolling gets intercepted by the horizontal ScrollViews.

Here is what my qml looks like:

```
ListView { //vertically scrolling list
    model: modelName
    anchors.fill: parent
    id: vListView
    delegate: Column {
        width: parent.width
        spacing: 3
        bottomPadding: 2
        Rectangle { // rectangles containing the text
            width: parent.width
            height: 40
            radius: 5
            id: buttonName

            ScrollView {//horizontally scrolling list
                contentHeight: -1
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.leftMargin: 18
                id: hScrollView
                Text {// text that is sometimes too long
                    width: parent.width
                    rightPadding: 15
                    bottomPadding: 5
                    text: model.data
                    topPadding: 9
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the list to scroll vertically and have the individual text boxes also scroll horizontally?

**edit:**

I've tried to use the following code to "catch" the scroll-wheel input and scroll the appropriate elements. But I hasn't been working out.
(code is placed in a mouse area that fills the whole thing)

```
onWheel: {
    if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0) {
        vListView.flickableItem.contentX -= vListView.scrollSpeed;
        if (vListView.flickableItem.contentX < 0) {
            vListView.flickableItem.contentX = 0;
        }
    } else {
        hScrollView.flickableItem.contentX += hScrollView.scrollSpeed;
        if (individualCommandScrollView.flickableItem.contentX + hScrollView.flickableItem.width > hScrollView.flickableItem.contentWidth) {
            hScrollView.flickableItem.contentX = hScrollView.flickableItem.contentWidth -  hScrollView.flickableItem.width;
        }
    }
}
onClicked: mouse.accepted = false;
onPressed: mouse.accepted = 
onReleased: mouse.accepted = false;
onDoubleClicked: mouse.accepted = false;
onPositionChanged: mouse.accepted = false;
onPressAndHold: mouse.accepted = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following solution using a `Flickable` instead of a `ScrollView` and a `MouseArea` to manually propagate the scroll to the horizontal `Flickable` when required.

The `Flickable` will not steal the mouse event from the parent `ListView` if the horizontal scroll on the text is not necessary.

Note that if all the texts are too long, you will never be able to scroll vertically on the main `ListView`...
I would recommend to imagine another design to handle long texts (text elide, wrap, multiline, ...).

```
ListView {
    id: vListView
    // ...
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: 40
        radius: 5

        Flickable {
            id: hScrollView
            contentHeight: -1
            contentWidth: text.paintedWidth   // <===== to allow horizontal scroll
            interactive: contentWidth > width // <===== but only if text is too long
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.leftMargin: 18

            Text {
                id: text
                width: parent.width
                rightPadding: 15
                bottomPadding: 5
                text: model.data
                topPadding: 9
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                enabled: hScrollView.interactive

                // manually scroll in Flickable on mouse wheel
                onWheel: {
                    let velocity = vListView.highlightMoveVelocity // use same velocity as the vertical ListView
                    let scrollValue = wheel.angleDelta.y >= 0 ? velocity : -velocity // move left or right according to wheel value
                    hScrollView.flick(scrollValue, 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to ListView:
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
Or add some margin to Rectangle and add borders or color to see where it is. So you will be able to point outside it and scroll ListView

Comment: Thank you Stephan, although this solution allows me to scroll vertically, it doesn't feel natural or intuitive (the cursor needs to be in a specific area etc.)
I was hoping that since the individual text-boxes don't need to be scrolled vertically, they would be some way to allow vertical scrolling.